# Creating GeoJSON from GRIB2 format using Python?

Tags: python, leaflet, polygon, geojson, grib

My ultimate goal is to create `geoJSON` from GRIB2 format using `Python` in order to display it at the `Leaflet`-open-street map.

I have the following data extracted from GRIBs:

**Multi-dimensional array of x's (lon)**

```
[[  0.     1.25   2.5  ... 356.25 357.5  358.75]  
 ...  
 [  0.     1.25   2.5  ... 356.25 357.5  358.75]]
```

**Multi-dimensional array of y's (lat)**

```
[[-90.   -90.   -90.   ... -90.   -90.   -90.  ]  
...  
[ 90.    90.    90.   ...  90.    90.    90.  ]]
```

**Multi-dimensional array of values**

```
[[5076. 5076. 5076. ... 5076. 5076. 5076.]  
...  
[5138. 5138. 5138. ... 5138. 5138. 5138.]]
```

As these arrays are related one-to-one to each other, number of elements in each is 42048.

How do I create `geoJSON` from them?

In order to draw it [chloropleth-like](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html)  in `Leaflet` (here is more info on [chloropleth-Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) if needed)

If I understand correctly, array of `[x, y, val]` will represent a `Point` and to draw the chloropleth (showing in colors values on the map) map I guess I need `Polygons`.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: You are trying to convert a raster into a vector format, while it might be technically possible it is unlikely to be a good solution to your problem.

Comment: @IanTurton, could you please advice in which direction to dig?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:

NOTE: You will need to install conda.

What this script does

1. Takes in .zip full of grib2 and loops over them
2. Makes some custom changes to the grib2 as a geopandas dataframe (you will need to customise this to your use case)
3. Outputs in geojson with a .index file to make it easier for your front end to read it in.

```
import xarray as xr
import cfgrib
import eccodes
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import json
import zipfile
import os
from os import walk

def extract_zip_file_and_return_list_of_file_names():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(cwd + "/assets/YOURFILENAME.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(cwd + "/assets/")

    dir_path = cwd + "/assets/YOURDIRNAME/YOURFILENAME"

    list_of_file_names = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(dir_path):
        list_of_file_names = filenames
        break

    return list_of_file_names



def process(list_of_grib2_filesnames):

    cwd = os.getcwd()
    list_of_json_filenames = []
    for filename in list_of_grib2_filesnames:
        print("Converting filename: " + filename)
        df = open_grib2_and_convert_to_dataframe(cwd + "/assets/YOURDIRNAME/" + filename)
        optomised_dataframe = optomise_dataframe(df)
        df_with_common_pressure_values = add_common_pressure_values_to_dataframe(optomised_dataframe)
        filename_in_json_format = write_to_json_file(df_with_common_pressure_values, filename)
        list_of_json_filenames.append(filename_in_json_format)

    write_to_json_file(list_of_json_filenames, cwd + "/index-file-name")

def open_grib2_and_convert_to_dataframe(file):
    data = xr.open_dataset(file, engine="cfgrib")
    # Convert grib2 into a geodataframe
    df = data.to_dataframe()
    return df


def optomise_dataframe(not_optomised_df):
    df = not_optomised_df.reset_index()
    try:
        geom = [Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['lon'], df['lat'])]
    except KeyError:
        geom = [Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]

    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geom)


    del gdf['time']
    del gdf['step']
    del gdf['latitude']
    del gdf['longitude']
    del gdf['valid_time']

    # Delete empty values of turb
    optomised_dataframe = gdf[gdf.turb != 0.0]

    return optomised_dataframe


def _get_all_common_pressure_values_in_file(df):
    drop = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['isobaricInhPa'])
    common_pressure_values_in_df = []
    for pressure in drop['isobaricInhPa']:
        common_pressure_values_in_df.append(pressure)
    return common_pressure_values_in_df


def add_common_pressure_values_to_dataframe(df):
    geojson_data = {
        "geojson": json.loads(df.to_json()),
        "common": _get_all_common_pressure_values_in_file(df)
    }
    return geojson_data


def write_to_json_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename + ".json", 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
        f.close()
    return filename + ".json"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_file_names = extract_zip_file_and_return_list_of_file_names()
    process(list_of_file_names)`
```